# What is the equation for 3D analog of the parabola (the paraboloid)  using cartesian co-ordinates?

Tags: conic-sections

In 2D, the equation is:

$y=4a(x-x_0)^2+c$

What is the equation for 3D analog of parabola?

Comment: Just for clarification: are you looking for the equation for the parabola as a curve in 3D, or are you looking for a 3D analogue of the parabola (for example, the paraboloid)?

Comment: @willie-wong: Thanks. I think I got my answer at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid)

Comment: @kritisen: to be clear, a parabola is a one-dimensional object in the sense that it has only length (like a string). So you were looking for the paraboloid? (I'm sorry if I'm repeating Willie, I just want to make sure you found what you were looking for).

Answer (score 1):

just as a guide for anyone who wants to know more visit

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid